# Machine Code based Control Flow Graph in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, machine-code, control-flow-graph, ssa

LLVM generally gives Control Flow Graphs (CFGs) for its intermediate representation (IR) language. You can also get high-level source-code-based CFGs with [little effort](http://adamrehn.com/articles/matching-cfg-blocks-to-basic-blocks/). I want to get CFGs at the level of Machine Code. Is there any way to get this?

I did a little bit of digging around. In LLVM's back-end code generation phase, there's a stage called [SSA-based Machine Code Optimizations](https://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#the-high-level-design-of-the-code-generator). There's not much information on this stage. However, I guess LLVM generates a SSA-based machine code in some intermediate stage. If such a stage exists, then we can have Basic Blocks based on the code at that stage. With those Basic Blocks, a CFG could be created on that stage. Can anybody give any clue on the source-file that I have to look in the LLVM source tree (possibly in `lib\CodeGen`) to find any information regarding this? Or the `class` that would give me SSA-based Machine Code walk-through and Basic Blocks? I would appreciate any pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

You need to write `MachineFunctionPass` for some target in `lib\Target\<target architecture>` folder.

Then in the `runOnMachineFunction(MachineFunction &MF)` function, you can view a CFG by calling the `MF.viewCFG()` function(in debug mode or with some tweaking inside the `viewCFG` to get CFG in Release mode as well).

You can access `MachineBasicBlock` and `MachineInstr` through the iterator over `MF`. Following is an example:

```
int i = 0;
for (auto &MBB : MF) {
    errs() << "Basic Block: " << i++ << "\n\n";
    for (auto &MI : MBB) {
      MI.print(errs(), true, false);
      errs() << "\n";
    }
}
```